# Como se puede coger un 'int' o 'float' en una 'entry' de tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estaba haciendo un programa en tkinter en el cual puedas poner un numero en un 'entry' de tkinter y al ponerlo que realice una operación y te la escriba en una etiqueta mi código es este:

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
window=tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("640x480")
hey = 4

caja = tkinter.Entry()
caja.pack()
caja.focus()

etiqueta = tkinter.Label(window, text = '', bg = 'white')
etiqueta.pack(side= tkinter.LEFT)

def textoCaja():
    texto = int(caja.get())
    
    op3 = 0.21 * texto
    op4 = op3 + texto
    text20 = op4.get()
    print(text20)

boton1 = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'click', command = textoCaja, width = 10, height = 5)
boton1.pack()



window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Te recomiendo mirar este artículo que explica las [Variables de TKinter](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm), tan solo tienes que asignarle la variable a tu input y a tu label y ... vaya, todo funciona automaticamente como magia! Además puedes cambiarle el trigger para que haga lo que quieras con el valor al modificarse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acá tienes una forma de hacerlo. Además, se muestra un mensaje de error si no se escribe un número.

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox

window=tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("640x480")
hey = 4

caja = tkinter.Entry()
caja.pack()
caja.focus()

v = StringVar()
etiqueta = tkinter.Label(window, textvariable=v, bg = 'white')
etiqueta.pack(side= tkinter.LEFT)


def textoCaja():  
    try:
        texto = float(caja.get())
        op3 = 0.21 * texto
        op4 = op3 + texto
        v.set(op4)
    except:
        messagebox.showerror('Mensaje', 'Sólo se permiten números.')
        caja.delete(0, END)

boton1 = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'click', command = textoCaja, width = 10, height = 5)
boton1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Tu código solo necesita un pequeño ajuste, dentro de `def textoCaja():`solo cambia:

```
texto = int(caja.get())
```

por:

```
texto = float(caja.get())
```

Por otro lado, tienes un error en `text20 = op4.get()`y esto es porque estás tratando `op4` como un valor a recuperar desde tkinter.

Tu función podría quedar así y operar con int y float:

```
def textoCaja():
    texto = float(caja.get())
    
    op3 = 0.21 * texto
    op4 = op3 + texto
    text20 = op4
    print(op4)
```

Aunque `text20` no es necesario, quedando así:

```
def textoCaja():
    texto = float(caja.get())
    
    op3 = 0.21 * texto
    op4 = op3 + texto
    print(op4)
```

Comment: Buena respuesta: +1.